# Google play policy compliance of "Provide access details"

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console, policy, privacy-policy

I am working on one application , published on google play and available only for indian users. Also the server apis, hosting India country only.All other countries traffic are avoided by backend servers.

As the result of that the login credentials are working inside India country only.
The same login credential I have shared inside the "App access" section on play console.

Recently I have received one policy compliance mail, that application is not accessible using that credentails, reason of this issue is , policy testers are using the application outside the hosted country.

As business point of view we don't want to open the traffic for outside India Country.

I already filed appeal with the screen recording to show the login works with entered credentials but didn't help.

Please suggest me on this. Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1):

Share testing purpose mobile no and email credential.

Mobile number with OTP ( When register/login verification )

or

Email id with OTP ( When register/login verification )
**( But unable to test some data's in your app maybe app has reject due to policy compliant )**

above method is not working you can use **global hosting service's**

Comment: Hi, I already shared with the email and password, but the login will work in hosting country.

Comment: I'm understand but " Play protect " employees can't test your app... Because play protect employees outside of India...

Comment: yes that's exactly the problem statement . Can you please suggest any solution for this , not global hosting.

Comment: Hi please wait... Will I share perfect method for this issue... DNS based solution...

Comment: Your using APIs domain name or ip address?

Comment: If your using ip address You need to go to your Site Tools > Security > Blocked Traffic > Block Country section: enable all countries when untill complete your app verify by Play protect. After you can only  india country only

Comment: thanks let me try with this one

Comment: a detailed screen-recording of the application helped to get the approval of the application from the play store reviewer team. Thanks for the help ! it is resolved without removing any restrictions.